# jQuery-ajax 'on click event' not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax to load certain pages, but the 'on-click' is not working. I created an init() function so one of the pages auto-loads when the page gets loaded. That works! However, when I click on any of the links, nothing gets loaded. In fact, nothing happens. Once a link is clicked, it's not going to the jQuery script. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Here are my links...

```
  <a href="#" id='add' >Add</a>                
<?php foreach($names as $name): ?>
  <a href="#" id="<?= $name['id']; ?>" class="league"><?= $name['name']; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<section id='main'>Main content</section>
```

Here is my jQuery script...

```
  var app = {      // this is a namespace
        nav: $('a.league'),  // selector
        content: $('section#main')     // section where id='main'
    };

    app.putContent = function(content){
        this.content.html(content);
    }

    app.loadPage = function(page){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../views/security.php',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            //data:{id: page},  // this works too
            data:"id=" + page,  
            success: function(data){
               app.putContent(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                app.putContent('Could not find page.');
            }
        });
    }

    app.init = function(){
        app.loadPage('add');   // this part works
        app.nav.on('click', function(){ // This part(on click) is not working
            var page = $($this).attr("id"); 
            app.loadPage(page);
        });

    }();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
var page = $($this).attr("id");
```

Into this:

```
var page = $(this).attr("id");
```

**Tip:**

- use your browser inspector/console to identify the problems in JS
  code

Comment: Feeling like a real idiot! I've been working on this for 4 days. I couldn't get this code out of my dreams. I swear, I thought this problem was going to put me over the edge...all because of a damn $ sign. Thank you Dusan for pulling me out of the abyss.